# AngularJS UI-Router loaded page control doesn't working without reload page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for routing. 
When i load a .html page using this code :

```
  $stateProvider.state("admin.cabletv.all-invoice", {
        url: "/all-invoice",
        templateUrl: "app/invoice/invoice-list.html",
        params: {
            'type': '1'
        },
        cache: false
    });
```

**invoice-list.html**

---

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-controller="pqsInvoiceListController as model">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">{{model.pageTitle}}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-8">
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="model.printInvoice()">Print</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div style="overflow-x: auto">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="model.selectedAll" ng-change="model.checkAll()" autocomplete="off" /></th>
                <th>In.&nbsp;no</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>Client&nbsp;Id</th>
                <th>Mobile&nbsp;No</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="invoice in model.invoices">
                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="model.idList[invoice.id].isSelected"/></td>
                <td>{{invoice.id}}</td>
                <td>{{invoice.invoiceType | pqsInvoiceType}}</td>
                <td>{{invoice.connection.client.name}}</td>
                <td>{{invoice.connection.client.id}}</td>
                <td>{{invoice.connection.client.mobileNumber1}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-if="model.invoices.length">
                <td colspan="12">Total</td>
                <td>{{model.totalAmount}}</td>
                <td colspan="4"></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>        
</div>
```

**Part of my controller**

```
(function (module) {

    var pqsInvoiceListController = function () {
        var vm = this;


        vm.idList = {};
        var buildIdList = function(invoices) {
            angular.forEach(invoices, function (invoice) {
                vm.idList[invoice.id] = {isSelected : false};
            });
        };

        vm.checkAll = function () {

            vm.selectedAll = !!vm.selectedAll;

            angular.forEach(vm.idList, function (id) {
                id.isSelected = vm.selectedAll;
            });
        };

    };

    module.controller("pqsInvoiceListController", pqsInvoiceListController);

}(angular.module("pqs.ui")));
```

*invoice-list.html* page is loaded, but the control(checkbox) in this page is not working. When i click checkbox it is not working. If i reload page using F5 then it works fine. How can i solve this problem without reloading page.

Comment: can you show your controller code?

Comment: why u not define controller in state like : 

**JS** 
$stateProvider.state("admin.cabletv.all-invoice", {
        url: "/all-invoice",
       controller : pqsInvoiceListController ,
       controllerAs : model,
        templateUrl: "app/invoice/invoice-list.html",
        params: {
            'type': '1'
        },
        cache: false
    });

**HTML**  
<div class="panel panel-primary">

..........

</div>

Comment: All's are working if i reload page. But at the first time it's not working.

Comment: I think controller is not any issue here. The main issue occurs at the time of loading **invoice-list.html** . In the first loading even mouse right button is not working.